# Error showing result JSON in listview in another activity

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

i'm a beginner here. I'm sorry for my bad english.

I have some trouble with my android project.

I have two `buttons` "jadwal" and "lokasi".

lokasi button must show json of "daftar-lokasi.php"

for more detail in my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gq4tjGRgsSA)

and it's my java [code][4]

what the code that I must add to show the `JSON` of "daftar-jadwal" in button's jadwal?

I just trial and error add duplicate `listviewadapters.java` but it's force close.

sory for my stupid question. :)

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: what is showing in your logcat ?

Comment: Please include the important parts of your code directly in the question, don't just add the code as an external link.

Comment: according to your code, `listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_jdw);` returns a null element. are you sure you have an item `listview_jdw` in `setContentView(R.layout.list_lokasi);`? Maybe you should have changed the layout name to `jadwal` or something. Anyway, thumbs up for making the video and presenting the code.

Comment: Post your Logcat here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I assume you copied the 2 activities (one from each other).
Since the code is the same, with only one major difference 
**Listitemjadwal.java**

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_jdw);
```

**listitemlokasi.java**

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

I assume you are not using the same layout for both activities although in your code i find in both activities

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_lokasi);
```

Correct the layout in your jadwal `Activity` and the issue should be solved.